# Calculate the percentage of occurances in a data set

Tags: python

I have a data set of `N` windspeed readings(m.s^-1), in this case 10, as an array `[2,3,3,4,4,4,4,6,5,5]`. I need to write a python program that reads the array and then graphs the windspeed vs the percentage of the time the wind is that speed or greater.

In this case, the wind speed is 2m.s^-1 or greater than 100%(1) of the time and 6m.s^-1 10%(0.1).

The example graph I am trying to achieve is to look like this, but the program I am trying to write needs to be able to take any sized data set.

[image: Graph Image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward implementation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_velocity_duration_curve(sites):
  for i, site in enumerate(sites, 1):
    windspeed = sorted(site, reverse=True)
    fractions = [j/len(site) for j in range(1, len(site)+1)]
    plt.plot(fractions, windspeed, '-o', label=f'site {i}')
  plt.legend(loc='upper right')
  plt.title('Velocity duration curves')
  plt.xlabel('Fraction of time')
  plt.ylabel('Wind speed (m/s)')
  plt.xticks([i/10 for i in range(1,11)])
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()

site1 = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5]
site2 = [2, 2, 6, 3, 7, 6, 1, 5, 6, 2]

plot_velocity_duration_curve([site1, site2])
```

[image]

And a more efficient implementation using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_velocity_duration_curve(sites):
  fractions = np.arange(1.,len(sites)+1) /len(sites)
  windspeed = np.sort(sites, axis=0)[::-1]
  lines = plt.plot(fractions, windspeed, '-o', label=f'site')
  plt.legend(lines, [f"site {i}" for i in range(1, len(lines)+1)])
  plt.title('Velocity duration curves')
  plt.xlabel('Fraction of time')
  plt.ylabel('Wind speed (m/s)')
  plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()


site1 = np.random.rayleigh(10,20)
site2 = np.random.rayleigh(9,20)
site3 = np.random.normal(10,5,20)
sites = np.c_[site1, site2, site3]
plot_velocity_duration_curve(sites)
```

[image]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49304517/50065) for an even more extensive implementation.